# LSTM Backpropagation in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

From official PTB google tutorial at the sector Truncated Backpropagation there is an implementation that uses BasicLSTMCell by creating a for loop that unrolls the graph for num_steps steps.

```
# Placeholder for the inputs in a given iteration.
words = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size, num_steps])

lstm = rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(lstm_size)
# Initial state of the LSTM memory.
initial_state = state = tf.zeros([batch_size, lstm.state_size])

for i in range(num_steps):
   # The value of state is updated after processing each batch of words.
   output, state = lstm(words[:, i], state)

# The rest of the code.
# ...

final_state = state
```

I have make an implementation using the BasicLSTMCell for predicting time series with the deference that I don't use any loop inside the graph but I update the lstmCells' state in a program execution loop. Here is the code:

```
input_layer = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [input_width, input_dim * 1])
lstm_cell1 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(input_dim * input_width)
lstm_state1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([input_width,lstm_cell1.state_size]))
lstm_output1, lstm_state_output1 = lstm_cell1(input_layer, lstm_state1, scope='LSTM1')
lstm_update_op1 = lstm_state1.assign(lstm_state_output1)

for i in range(39000):
    input_v, output_v = get_new_input_output(i, A)
    _, _, network_output = sess.run([lstm_update_op1, train_step, final_output],
                                feed_dict={input_layer: input_v, correct_output: output_v})
```

How is the second implementation implements tha backpropagation through time and is this a proper use of lstmCell at tensorflow. Personaly I prefer the second implementation because I found It much clearer and is also able to support streaming of data. But the fact that google present the first implementation makes me suspicious that I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for backpropagation through time to work during training, the graph needs to store the values of all tensors during the forward pass so that it can use them during the reverse pass to compute the gradients. In your code, the forward pass should word fine (I have not tested it, though), but the reverse pass cannot work since the graph cannot preserve the tensor values during the forward pass (because of the `assign()` op).

I suggest you look at [this great post](https://danijar.com/introduction-to-recurrent-networks-in-tensorflow/) by Danijar Hafner. It explains how to use the `dynamic_rnn()` function to do what you want.